# Switch from mySQL to mariaDB timestamp messup

Tags: php, pdo, mariadb

I have switched from MySQL to MariaDB which has caused some "minor" problems. One has been bugging me for hours now and i can't find the solution.

I moved my database by exporting it from MySQL and importing it into MariaDB which went well..

When one of my update queries did not work i narrowed it down to this function in my database handler:

```
public function updateEquipment($type,$product,$acquisition,$calibration_interval,$equipment_no,$inspection_date,$equipment_id,$active)
    {       
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE equipment SET type = :type, acquisition = :acquisition, calibration_interval = :calibration_interval, equipment_no = :equipment_no, product = :product, inspection_date = :inspection_date, active = :active WHERE id = :equipment_id");

        $stmt->bindParam(":equipment_id", $equipment_id,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(":type", $type,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":acquisition", $acquisition,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":calibration_interval", $calibration_interval,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":equipment_no", $equipment_no,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":product", $product,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":inspection_date", $this->formatDateStrToTimeStamp($inspection_date),PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(":active", $active,PDO::PARAM_INT);
        return $stmt->execute();        
    }
```

**formatDateStrToTimeStamp function:**

```
private function formatDateStrToTimeStamp($inspection_date)
    {
        $day = substr($inspection_date,0,2);
        $month = substr($inspection_date,3,2);
        $year = substr($inspection_date,6,4);   
        return date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($year."-".$month."-".$day));
    }
```

As you can see, i have switched out the binding of my inspection_date with a string representing the timestamp i want to update. I tested the statement WITHOUT updating my timestamp and then it was working as expected. As soon as i add the timestamp (in my case i have inserted a static timestamp) the row will NOT update and execute does not return (it should return true or false).

**Heres my table structure:**

```
CREATE TABLE `equipment` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` text NOT NULL,
  `acquisition` text NOT NULL,
  `calibration_interval` text NOT NULL,
  `equipment_no` text NOT NULL,
  `product` text NOT NULL,
  `inspection_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `active` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

**Question:** Are timestamps treated different in mariaDB, because i have not made any changes to my code since the switch, and i have simply imported my database from the export i made from my MySQL database.

Comment: Hmm, may I suggest you always 'bindValue' unless using `BLOB`? Also, your function returns an 'sql date' not a `timestamp` which has format "U"?

Comment: @RyanVincent would that mean that i could both write a string when binding or use return values from functions ? .. If so .. why did they make a bindParam if the bindValue offers all that bindParam does and MORE :)

Comment: `bindParam` provides speed if dealing with very large amounts of data. However, for most situations it isn't worth it. in your case you could just provide the values in an array to the `execute` statement directly, which does an automatic 'bindValue'. It simplifies the code significantly.

Comment: It doesn't provide more. If you want, or need, to  use `bindParam` then that is what is required. However, for most queries, `bindValue` is a lot easier and avoids various issues. `Binding by value` is not available in `native mysqli`. You have to `bind by param`. However, PDO does all the work of generating the variables for you when using `bindValue`.

Comment: @RyanVincent Thanks for the advice .. i will change my bindings

Comment: What was in `$inspection_date` coming into the function?  Why do you need the function at all?

Comment: Perhaps you needed `FROM_UNIXTIME()` in the `UPDATE`; nothing special in PHP.

Comment: Isn't TimeStamp automatically updated with the System time and date?  IOW, you're not supposed to pass any values to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After debugging my pants off (because im not very good at debugging web applications) i finally found the answer to my problem.

**PDO's bindparam must bind a variable to a placeholder or questionmark** which is also stated in the pdo documentation. In my case i tried both inserting a string directly when binding, and the original code with the error used the return value of a timestamp formater. In both cases i didn't use a variable when binding to my placeholder, hence the error....

I came across the the error when i debugged the function using Chrome's Advanced Rest Client which revealed an error: *"Only variables should be passed by reference"*.

**Solution 1:**

```
$inspect = $this->formatDateStrToTimeStamp($inspection_date);
$stmt->bindParam(":inspection_date", $inspect,PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

**Solution 2:**

As pointed out by Ryan Vincent in the comments use bindValue instead (see his comment for further inspiration)

**But still a bit confused:**
I'm still a bit confused though, as the code previously ran on another host without problems. I cannot remember the PHP version or anything, but if someone could confirm that it was possible in previous version it would explain why...

Comment: I know this is a problem when trying to bind values,`>bindParam(":col",123)` because bindparam passes by reference but its not clear to me that  passing directly a function is not considered a reference.Someone in the know clear that up.

Comment: @Mihai, a function, when it executes, returns a value. However, only PHP knows where that value is stored. It could be on the stack, work area, CPU registers etc. Whatever, It isn't going to tell us. Taking a 'reference' directly of the result is 'problematic' at best. It may beimpossible. You can store it somewhere so you know where it is. And then take a reference of that?